# php - Get values from database and set them in an array 1tomany

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to get some values from the database and set them in an array! 
The array must be in the format of year : months available for this year.

I have multiple dates from different years and I need to take a distinct value for each year and a the months available for that year and set them in an array which will then be send to an ajax call and put the values in two dropdown lists (one for years and the other for months).

***PHP CODE***

```
$select_all = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) AS year, monthname(date) as month 
    FROM salaries 
    where employee_id = '$employeeid1'")or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

$year = array();
while($years = mysqli_fetch_array($select_all)) {
   $year[] = $years;
}
    foreach ($year as $years) {
        $year_array[] = array(
        'year' => $years["year"],
        'month' => $years["month"]

            );
    }
    echo json_encode($year_array);
```

***jQuery***

```
<script>
$("#employee_id").on("change", function(){
    var employeeid = $("#employee_id").val();
    console.log('ID is: ' + employeeid);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'queries.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {employeeid: employeeid},
        success: function(data) {
            var getarray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            var year = getarray.year;
            var month = getarray.month;

            console.log('DATAAAA: ' + data);
            $("#c_year").html('<option value = ' + year + '>' + year + '</option>');
            $("#c_month").html('<option value = ' + month + '>' + month + '</option>');


    },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

my main page gives me an error of

***error***

> parsererror
>       index.php:102 SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0
>           at JSON.parse ()
>           at n.parseJSON (jquery-2.1.3.js:4)
>           at uc (jquery-2.1.3.js:4)
>           at x (jquery-2.1.3.js:4)
>           at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-2.1.3.js:4)

and when i echo my results i get null... any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Use your browser dev tools, network panel, to first of all check what your server actually returned in response to this AJAX request.

Comment: [{"year":"0","month":null}]

Comment: When you use `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery will automatically decode the returned data as JSON. Trying to do that _again_ (`jQuery.parseJSON(data)`) is likely your error here.

Comment: Your code potentially is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. It's not clear where `$employeeid1` comes from, but it would be a lot safer to parameterise it

Comment: everything works locally and they are for testing purposes @ADyson

Comment: It's still a good habit to get into, it's not much more work to write it properly. You also get the added benefit of not running into strange syntax errors due to unexpected input like quote marks etc. And "test" code often has a habit of turning into "live" code once it works nicely (not always directly, but the working snippet gets copied/pasted etc).

Comment: any idea tho why i get the error?  @ADyson

Comment: I think it's quite likely to be what CBroe already said above. `data` should already be an object. JSON.parse expects a string as input, not an object. You should just able to use `data` directly in your script. `dataType: 'json'` is a hint to jQuery to automatically parse the response as JSON for you, and give you `data` as a ready-made object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the php part i used this and it works fine. I am using an array which i im assign the first column so that the second one will have all the equivalent months pf each year!

```
$select_all = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) AS year, monthname(date) AS month 
    FROM table 
    where e_id = '$eid' ORDER BY YEAR(date), Month(date)")or die(mysqli_error());

$json   = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_all)){


    $year = $row['year'];
    $month = $row['month'];
    if (!array_key_exists($year, $json)){
        $json[$year] = array();
    }
    array_push($json[$year], $month);       
}

echo json_encode($json);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your ajax request response like this :

[{year: "2015", month: "Jan"},{year: "2016", month: "Jan"},{year: "2018", month: "Jan"}]

to fetch year and month, your jquery code should be like this :

```
var getarray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

for(var loop=0; loop< getarray.length; loop++)
{
var year = getarray[loop].year;
var month = getarray[loop].month;
}
```

if your ajax response like this:

{year:"2017",month:"Sep"}

to fetch year and month, your jquery code should be like this :

```
var getarray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var year = getarray.year;
var month = getarray.month;
```